# Web Component / HtmlElement : unit testing

Tags: html, unit-testing, web-component, web-component-tester

I'm trying to test a web component.
Here is my project structure :

```
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app.js
│   └── index.html
└── test
    └── hello-world-test.html
```

Here is my working code :

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback () {
      this.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!'
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to test that web component with `web-component-tester`.
I installed the utility globally :

```
npm install -g web-component-tester
```

I declared it in the `package.json` file :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "^6.9.0"
}
```

then, I wrote my test in the `test` folder and saved it to `hello-world-test.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../node_modules/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <test-fixture id="hello-world-fixture">
            <hello-world></hello-world>
    </test-fixture>
    <script>
        suite('<hello-world>', function(){
            let component = document.querySelector('hello-world');

            test('contains hello world string ?', () => {
                let index = component.innerText.indexOf('Hello');
                assert.isAtLeast(index, 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I typed :

```
wct --npm
```

Then obtained the following error in Chrome :

[image: Here is the result in Chrome]

What am I missing to run the test correctly ?
The only decent materials I've found are [this one](https://bendyworks.com/blog/native-web-components) and [that one](https://github.com/pearlbea/mini-form) but they are outdated.

Comment: You're also missing a constructor with a super() call to initiate the correct prototype chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors :

- First, please read the **whole** documentation as in the last paragraph it's clear that for those who use `npm` you need an additional dependency through the `wctPackageName` :

> Components which wish to support npm-based installation should include
>   wct-browser-legacy in their devDependencies, which is a package that
>   contains only the client-side javascript necessary for executing WCT
>   tests in an npm-based environment. WCT will attempt to identify which
>   package provides the client-side code by checking for compatible
>   packages in the following order of preference: wct-mocha,
>   wct-browser-legacy and web-component-tester. If you want to specify
>   which package provides WCT client-side code, use the
>   --wct-package-name flag or wctPackageName option in wct.conf.json with the npm package name.

So you will need to add `wct-browser-legacy` in your `devDependencies`

- Giving your project structure, you are including the `app.js` as if it was at the same level. It should be `../src/app.js`.
- You should add the `type="module"` to that import
- You declared a fixture but didn't take profit of it through the function [`fixture`](https://github.com/polymerelements/test-fixture)

If I had to correct your code :

- The command should be `wct --npm -wct-package-name=wct-browser-legacy`. Or even better create a `wct.conf.js` file with the following information :

```js
module.exports = {
    npm:true,
    verbose: true,
    plugins: {
        local: {
            browsers: ["chrome"]
        }
    },
    wctPackageName: "wct-browser-legacy"
};
```

- Your test should be modified as following :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../node_modules/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <test-fixture id="helloWorldFixture">
        <template>
            <hello-world>
            </hello-world>
        </template>
    </test-fixture>
    <script>
        suite('<hello-world>', () => {
            let component;
            setup(() => {
                component = fixture('helloWorldFixture');
            });

            test('contains hello world string ?', () => {
                let index = component.innerText.indexOf('Hello');
                assert.isAtLeast(index, 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, notice that I used the fixture's id and put the component initialisation in the `setup` function.

Comment: your WCT knowledge seems to be pretty big - may I ask you to review an "alternative" e.g. karma with some settings... here are the details https://open-wc.org/recommendations/testing.html would love your feedback :)

Comment: @Zakaria please can you look at my issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064334/during-wct-test-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of? I tried to reproduced all you suggested but I am facing problems

Answer (score 1):

Zakaria's answer is good, but I suggest ditching wct-browser-legacy in favor of wct-mocha as it is lighter-weight and doesn't have out-of-date dependencies like old version of lodash and sinon etc.

See the README for full details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wct-mocha

tl;dr version:

```
$ npm rm --save wct-browser-legacy
$ npm install --save-dev \
  @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs \
  @polymer/test-fixture \
  wct-mocha \
  mocha \
  chai
```

You shouldn't *need* to specify it, but if you have wct.conf.js file you should change an existing wctPackageName entry to:

```
wctPackageName: "wct-mocha"
```

Your HTML needs to change a little and you need to make sure mocha is a direct dependency, since wct-mocha will not autoload.  You'd also need to do that with chai if you're using chai assertions and `@polymer/test-fixture` if you use those.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script> 
  <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script> 
  <script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script> 
  <script src="../node_modules/@polymer/test-fixture/test-fixture.js"></script> 
  <script src="../node_modules/wct-mocha/wct-mocha.js"></script> 
</head>
```